# Jekyll place variable inside logic expression

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm trying to do the following:

```
{% for post in site.categories.{{ post.designer }} %}
```

So that when placing the above code inside a single post, it can display a list of posts from the current post's category.

However I don't think it's working because it just keeps returning undefined. My question is, is it possible in Jekyll or Liquid to place variables inside logic expressions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that "designer" is the category of your post?
If yes, you can't get it via `post.designer`.

You need to use `page.categories` instead (according to [Page variables](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/#page-variables)).

A post can have more than one category, so you can't just place `page.categories` in your loop because it's an array.

There are two possible solutions:

1. Loop through all the categories of the post, and then do your loop for each category:

   ```
   {% for cat in page.categories %}
     <h1>{{ cat }}</h1>
     <ul>
       {% for post in site.categories[cat] %}
         <li><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
       {% endfor %}
     </ul>
   {% endfor %}
   ```
2. If your post has only one category, you can omit the outer loop from my first example and just use [the first element of the `page.categories` array](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-basics/output#first):

   ```
   <ul>
     {% for post in site.categories[page.categories.first] %}
       <li><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
     {% endfor %}
   </ul>
   ```

   or

   ```
   {% assign firstcat = page.categories | first %}

   <ul>
     {% for post in site.categories[firstcat] %}
       <li><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
     {% endfor %}
   </ul>
   ```